# 3D printing with Blender - Cylinder printing with holes - without internal support

Tags: 3d-printing

[image]

Blender and 3D printing beginner here.

First of all I'm using Ultimaker Cura and Blender of course, with an Ender 3 Pro to print.

I need to print this cylinder with extruded paths. How do I go about it? I'm struggling to set the printer to support the structure internally. The blue on this image is an external support. The grey parts at the top of the half cylinder laying down is just absent of filament, so when I print this it gets to this point and basically breaks.

So how can I fix this? I used a solidify modifier in Blender but it doesn't seem to make a difference if I do or don't..

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I think this is really a Cura and not Blender question.  If I understand Cura, you merely need to provide it a blend file of the final object and it will add the supports; so getting it to do internal instead of external is a question for their forum or support